# What SATA HDDs do not require 12V power?

Tags: hard-drive, sata

Looking to buy a Ubiquiti Cloud Key Gen 2 that takes a SATA 6Gb/s HDD up to 5TB. The [drive compatibility sheet](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037340954-UniFi-Protect-Hard-Drive-Compatibility#6) says "* The Cloud Key Gen2 Plus does not support Hard Drives that require a 12V supply in addition to the default 5V supply." The only compatible drive it lists is Seagate BarraCuda   ST5000LM000 5TB. But when I look at the specs for that drive, I don't see anything that says it doesn't need the 12V power pin that is standard for SATA. How would I know if there might be other drives that don't need 12V power that are not listed on the Ubiquiti sheet? I'm not really likely to buy a drive that's not listed as compatible, just trying to learn.

Comment: The spec sheet only lists 5V power. That’s a strong indicator.

Comment: @DanielB Okay, I do see that only 5V is mentioned on the spec sheet for that particular drive. But if I look at the spec sheet for Western Digital Blue 2.5" HDDs (https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/internal-drives/wd-blue-hdd/product-brief-western-digital-wd-blue-mobile-sata-hdd.pdf), the power section doesn't mention either 12V or 5V or 3.3V. What does that indicate?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the current-gen 2.5" and 1.8" and SSDs only draw from 5v and mSATA/mPCIe all use 3.3v

Comment: Good to know, but the Ubiquiti compatibility sheet in my question listed only the BarraCuda ST5000LM000 as compatible. If most 2.5" internal HDDs required only 5V power I'd think there would be several compatible drives. As noted in my comment to @Daniel B, the Western Digital Blue 2.5" internal HDDs say nothing about voltage in the section on power management. I'm trying to learn how I can know for sure if a particular drive only needs 5V power, and it seems spec sheets don't always say. "most current-gen" isn't super helpful since "most" isn't "all", and "current-gen" isn't  very specific.